# Flask + Firestore adding all doc elements to a dictionary {not looping}

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

#### I must be doing something wrong

I'm trying to loop through all documents in a collection and add the contents to a dictionary.

I added the data to a dictionary, but my intention was to loop through all docs:

```
firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()
blog_col = db.collection(u'blog')


class Art_cont:
    def __init__(self,title,date,link):
        self.title = title
        self.date = date
        self.link = link



def getLast4():
    query = blog_col.order_by("date").limit_to_last(4).get()
    for doc in query: #Need to find a way to loop through all docs, this doesn't work
        db_title=doc.to_dict()["title"]
        db_date=doc.to_dict()["date"]
        db_link=doc.to_dict()["link"]
        content1=Art_cont(db_title,db_date,db_link)
        #here wrap them up with html and return them to app
    print(content1.title,content1.date,content1.link)
```

When I run that code it only gives me the first doc content:

[image]

Vs the other docs that have the same structure:

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I almost had it, I ended up creating a function instead:

```
def getlist(x):
    query = blog_col.order_by("date").limit_to_last(4).get()
    docs=[]
    for doc in query: 
        docs.append(doc)

    docnum=docs[x]
    db_title=docnum.to_dict()["title"]
    db_date=docnum.to_dict()["date"]
    db_link=docnum.to_dict()["link"]
    content=Art_cont(db_title,db_date,db_link)
    return content

print(getlist(0).title)
print(getlist(1).title)

etc...
```

Hope this helps anyone in a similar situation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that query is an object of your model, write `db_title = doc.your_attribute_name.to_dict()['title']` and do the same for the other attributes.